# What kind of component this is (ST e3 ZOM Y734)?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, powermosfet, igbt, st

please help to identify following electronic component from the image:
[image]

It is clearly seen all symbols:

```
ST e3
ZOM
Y734
```

So it's definitely "STMicroelectronics".
However, I could not find any information about this electronic component either on the official website or on the Internet.

P.S. This component is a part of a Daikin air conditioner's main board.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [STM Z0110MN](https://datasheet.datasheetarchive.com/originals/scans/Scans-023/ScansEX68419.pdf) [TRIAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC). The `TR101` designator also hints at a TRIAC. The actual part code is Z0M.

[image]

I chose this picture, because STM changed the marking style in newer batches.

[image]

(Source: [ebay.com](https://www.ebay.de/itm/222790352254?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=707-134425-41852-0&mkcid=2&mkscid=101&itemid=222790352254&targetid=1404115579373&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9043715&poi=&campaignid=17935704717&mkgroupid=139162549385&rlsatarget=pla-1404115579373&abcId=9301059&merchantid=110933354&gclid=Cj0KCQjwoK2mBhDzARIsADGbjepPBaRLbjZf2vg5xtgjr7ws1ID9FhyTvA3-r3HwjHhmS3aYy9HyB_waAnSIEALw_wcB))

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a real pro!

Comment: @lollol The table is from the datasheet I linked. I found the datasheet by searching `st microelectronics "ZOM" marking`. It's the first result. Luckily the OCR software also misread the 0 as O ;) This type of search is always the first thing I do. Usually it's not successful, but here I got lucky.

Comment: Again, thank you for your comment! I deleted my previous stupid question because I found the alias information right after I sent you my question about table origin :) BTW, I made same mistake misreading 0 as O.